# Direct Mapped Cache Bits

Tags: caching, assembly, memory, cpu-architecture

So Im having trouble understanding some parts to direct mapped caching. I have a byte addressed memory system that has 64KB memory with a 2KB direct-mapped cache. Cache blocks are 32 bytes.

From what I understand and please correct me if i'm wrong, I have 2048B/32B = 64 cache blocks. I need to figure out how many total bits are needed for each cache entry (tag, "dirty" bit, etc).

I believe i'll need 6 index bits (2^6 = 64 (# of blocks))
and 5 offset bits (2^5 = 32 (size of cache block))
Im just having trouble figuring out the rest that are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bits of a physical address can be split into 3 groups - the least significant group of bits that determine "offset of byte within cache block" and doesn't need to be stored in the tag, the middle group of bits that determine "index of cache block within the cache" and doesn't need to be stored in the tag, and the most significant group of bits that is used to check if the data in the cache is the data you want which must be stored in the tag.

With 64 KiB of physical address space a physical address would have 16 bits; and if your cache is 2048 bytes then (for "direct mapped") the least significant group of bits and the middle group of bits combined must add up to a total of 11 bits. That means the most significant group of bits (which must be stored in the tag) needs to be 5 bits (because 16 bits - 11 bits = 5 bits).

For other bits; you always need something to indicate if the entry is used or empty; if the cache is "write-back" you need a dirty bit but if the cache is "write-through" you don't; if there are multiple CPUs and cache coherency you need more bits for that (e.g. exclusive/shared); and if there's any kind of error detection or correction you need more bits for that (e.g. a "parity bit"). This means the total tag size is at least 6 bits (but may be more).